# Notification in JavaFX when any property changes

Tags: javafx, properties

Is there a way to have a notification if ANY one (or even better, any one from a specific GROUP) of properties of a node in JavaFX changes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the same invalidation listener to all of them?

Comment: It's hard to see a use case for this which didn't involve creating a binding that was bound to the properties of interest. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @sillyfly

Thank you very much. I 'll try sillyfly's method as follows:

    property1..addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Object>      observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) -> {
    // doSomething();});
    property2..addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Object>      observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) -> {
    // doSomething();});

Answer (score 0):

Actually I also don't know the reason why you want to do something like this, but if you don't want to repeat yourself for every property, you could do something like this:

```
ObservableList<Property<?>> propList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private void doSomething(Observable observable){
    System.out.println("Handled" + observable.toString());
}

private void attachListener(Property<?> p){
    p.addListener(new InvalidationListener() {

        @Override
        public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
            doSomething(observable);

        }
    });
}

// In start, or whereever you want to add the properties
propList.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Property<?>>(){

    @Override
    public void onChanged(javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Property<?>> change) {
        while(change.next()){
            if(change.wasAdded())
                for(Property<?> item : change.getAddedSubList()){attachListener(item);}
        }
    }

});

BooleanProperty a = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false); 
BooleanProperty b = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
IntegerProperty c = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);

propList.addAll(a,b,c);

a.set(true);
a.set(false);
b.set(true);
c.set(2);
```

Output is:

```
HandledBooleanProperty [value: true]
HandledBooleanProperty [value: false]
HandledBooleanProperty [value: true]
HandledIntegerProperty [value: 2]
```

What it does:

You add the properties to an `ObservableList`, and when the list gets a new element, your handler is attached as `InvalidationListener`, therefore you can control the property set by adding element to the list rather than adding the listener one-by-one.